# Properties of amenable groups

Tags: topological-groups, amenability

Let $G$ be an amenable countable group. Why does every subgroup and homomorphic image of $G$ is amenable? Further more, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and both $N$ and $G/N$ are amenable, why does $G$ must be amenable?

Comment: Working with the characterization of amenability for countable (discrete) groups by existence of a left-invariant finitely additive probability measure ([finite mean](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/some-notes-on-amenability/)) $\mu_G$, all these properties are natural and not too difficult. Except for the one we would expect to be easier: amenability passes to subgroups $H$ (the problem is when $\mu_G(H)=0$, which is equivalent to $[G:H]=\infty$). For this one, the Folner condition, for instance, works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V. Runde, Lectures on Amenability. Springer, 2002 (Lecture notes in mathematics ; 1774). Section 2.3 "Hereditary properties"